# Unmount a rbind mount without affecting the original mount

Tags: linux, mount, linux-kernel, unmount

There is another [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120827/recursive-umount-after-rbind-mount) discussing about umounting rbind mounts, but the solution has unwanted effect.  Consider the following directory layout:

```
.
├── A_dir
│   └── mount_b
├── B_dir
│   └── mount_c
└── C_dir
```

Now I bind `C_dir` to `B_dir/mount_c` and rbind `B_dir` to `A_dir/mount_b`:

```
[hidden]$ sudo mount --bind C_dir B_dir/mount_c
[hidden]$ sudo mount --rbind B_dir A_dir/mount_b
[hidden]$ mount | grep _dir | wc -l
3
```

Now `umount A_dir/mount_b` will fail, which is not surprising.  According to the answers everywhere on the web, we need to `umount A_dir/mount_b/mount_c` first then `umount A_dir/mount_b`. However, `umount A_dir/mount_b/mount_c` will also unmount `B_dir/mount_c`, which is unwanted:

```
[hidden]$ sudo umount A_dir/mount_b/mount_c
[hidden]$ mount | grep _dir | wc -l
1
```

Now my question is, how do I unmount `A_dir/mount_b` but leaving `B_dir` unaffected, i.e. there is still a bind `B_dir/mount_c` to `C_dir`?

Thanks.

Comment: I've been noticing this for *non*-recursive bind mounts.  /subscribe.  http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269695/mounting-new-filesystem-affects-non-recursive-bind-mounts

Answer (score 3):

Found it.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/276700/29483

Try `--make-rprivate`:

```
mount --make-rprivate A_dir
umount -R A_dir
```

Note: systemd people, who set your described behaviour as the new default, recommend that you would not make the rbind mount private initially.  It's ok to do just before unmount though.

It's because when you clone all the mounts, you might e.g. then need to eject a CD.  If it was mounted at clone-time, enabling propagation means you only need to run umount on one location only (e.g. outside the rbind mount, just like normal), and then you'll be able to eject it.